# asp.net <%%> auto parse

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a code in my website

```
<link href="<%=ResourceUrl %>PointMall/css/jjh_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
media="screen" />
```

on browser be changed

```
<link href="&lt;%=ResourceUrl %>PointMall/css/jjh_style.css?t=1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Why? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes. Eg:

```
<link href='<%= ResourceUrl + "PointMall/css/jjh_style.css" %>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes if you have `/` in the ResourceUrl

```
<link href='<%= ResourceUrl + "PointMall/css/jjh_style.css" %>' rel="stylesheet" 
           type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Other wise

```
<link href='<%= ResourceUrl + "/PointMall/css/jjh_style.css" %>' rel="stylesheet" 
           type="text/css" media="screen" />
```